# Swing application error: java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: java, swing

I have this problem with my swing application: "java.lang.classnotfoundexception com.mysql.jdbc.driver with swing". When I created a connection I added mysql connector lib file and I made a test. It was successful. Now I am connected and I can see every table in my database. The problem is when I want to create a simple select query.

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Sample";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "123";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
      }
}
```

Comment: How are you running your application when it fails? For example, is this through Eclipse, or is it already compiled? The exception suggests that your MySQL lib is not in the classpath.

Comment: I run my app normally and when I click on the button which call the select query I see the error.

Comment: I would double-check to make sure your MySQL library is actually in the classpath.

Comment: @user1107922 : Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230), hopefully this might be able to give you some idea how to put a .jar file to your classpath, to atleast make this program work. But first try to run your project with this command `java -classpath pathToJARFile/myJARFile.jar;.; packageName.ClassNameWithMainMethod` Now press Enter. No need to specify .class after Class Name.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the driver class in your classpath when you run.  Add the MySQL JAR to your runtime classpath.

There's lots wrong with your code.  There's no reason to hard code this for only MySQL.  It's bad form to have all that info in plain text that way.  You could move it out into a properties file.  You'll need more methods than this (e.g. closing connections, etc.)

Comment: How should I add this jar to my runtime classpath? I can't understand what is my classpath in swing application. This is first app which I code.

Comment: It's the same as a non-Swing application: what you tell the JVM when you run.  Look at the -classpath option on java.exe.

Comment: I tried this: "java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar Client.classes.client.DatabaseManager.class" but I have this error:Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...Could not find the main class: Client.classes.client.DatabaseManager.class. Program will exit.

Comment: Wrong, as you can see.  You've got the JAR correct; now you need to tell it how to find your class with the main method.  Your package name is certainly confusing.  You need to add the directory that's the parent of your package structure to the classpath next.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid answer but I can't make it working. I put the jar in the directory Project. I have this structure: Project/Client/classes/client and there I have two class files - HomePage.class with the main method and DatabaseManager.class with the source which I wrote.

Comment: I tried and this one: CLASSPATH=".:/home/user/Project/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.bin.jar". I do not have an error but it isn't working..

Comment: You can't write Java successfully until you understand CLASSPATH.  No IDE can help you.  You ran it; you did not get an exception; you did not get an error; you didn't get some expected result.  This is progress - it means your ClassNotFound issues are over.  You've got another problem.  Sounds like you're swallowing an exception that would tell you what's wrong if you were printing the stack trace to the console.