# Add components to JPanel from another jar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jar, executable-jar

I start write app through Java 4 months ago, and yesterday I got exception: 
my code is to large. In Visual studio and c# it wasn't.

How can I make app with more jar file?

I need about 25 panels (`JPanel`) which contains another components. How can I make them (the panels) separately in jars and then include the panels to my main app?

How can I move parameters to or from the jars?

Sorry for my English, and I hope that my questions are clear and you understand what I mean.

Comment: i suppose that it would be better that you bind the jpanels in a single jar file. Is it quite necessary for you have the jpanels in different jar files?

Comment: What is the exact exception for: 'my code is too large'? The only cases where this can occur is when you exceed the JVM class file limits. Nevertheless the exact Exception (and stack trace) would me helpful.

Comment: `I got exception: my code is to large` - Can you post the exception output? I doubt that moving some of your code into jar files solves this.

Comment: *"Thanks Viktor."*  Don't include sigs. in questions.

Comment: Hope this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230), might be of some help on the topic !!

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like in void initComponents() method .You are initializing 25 panel and adding components.My suggestion my find out common behaviour among urs panel.After a indentify it  create a class that extends Jpanel.In extended Jpanel give implemenation to common behaviour.So,all japanel share it among.If you want to use jpanel specific behaviour use super().If u want to use common specific behaviour like Layout,colour and many more stuffs,use it from common.It will  helps u lot for code duplication and more management.Create a separate inner classes for panel or you can use separate class that extends Jpanel.Hope it will help you.

Comment: I created my app in netbeans in designer mode. I add components and some parts of code netbeans create automatically. Bat in app I need so many components. Now i try recreate the one of 25 panels(it is big panel with many components like little panels tables buttons, checkbox atc.) in class without main class with their events an functions. I will delete this panel from current project and finally  I have to find way how it implement to project.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is problem in doing this. Is  25 J panels are harder to maintain ?You can divide it in different package structure according to yours  requirement.Would you please tell about yours panels structure.Do they share common behavior.Are you using Swing panel or extended one?

Comment: here is my excwption \Genius1.java:396: error: code too large
    private void initComponents() {
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
C:\Users\vycvlt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Genius\nbproject\build-impl.xml:940: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\vycvlt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Genius\nbproject\build-impl.xml:293: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: here is part of biuld.xml fom line 940   <target depends="init,deps-jar,-pre-pre-compile,-pre-compile, -copy-persistence-xml,-compile-depend" if="have.sources" name="-do-compile">
        <j2seproject3:javac gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"/>
        <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="${build.classes.excludes},${excludes}" includes="${includes}"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

Comment: here is part of biuld.xml fom line 293    <javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
                    <src>
                        <dirset dir="@{gensrcdir}" erroronmissingdir="false">
                            <include name="*"/>
                        </dirset>
                    </src>

Comment: I can't post image i am new on this forum i need 10 reputation.