# Expose JPanel to external jar

Tags: java, swing, jar, jpanel

I have a Java SWING program with basically a single, simple window. The window contains a menu an a JPanel. Ideally, I'd want to use the menu to choose an external jar file (which is another SWING program) and run it. The jar should then execute in the background and use the JPanel in my window instead of creating a new window on its own.
Would this be possible? My guess is that I should somehow "expose" or "make available" my JPanel to the external application, but I can't figure out how I could do this. Even a simple code snippet would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230). I hope it can help you somewhere :-) The answer below, is inline with helping you in the desired direction. Though the answer in my link, has nothing to do with the situation, though it might can help you understand, how to use an external jar in a given project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to load the external `Jar` in a custom class loader to make it available to your application to run.  Something like [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) should be capable of doing the trick.

Your application and external Jar should use a common, known, interface(s) that they can communicate through.  This allows you to load the external jar, find and load the required "entry" class and run it.

This `interface` should provide some kind of registration for notification/callback mechanism (AKA a listener), which you application can attach to the external "task" and which the external class could then use to provide notification of changes back to your application.

You should avoid, where possible, exposing more of you application to the external Jar then you have to.  This reduces the risk of the external Jar messing with your application, or indeed, needing to even care about it...

You could use either the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and [Producer/Consumer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), depending on your needs

More on the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)