# Java import external jar file

Tags: java, jar, import, classpath

Say I have TryJar.java in ~/jar/

```
public class TryJar {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

then I type:

```
javac TryJar.java
jar cf TryJar.jar TryJar.class
```

I want to import this class in another source file in ~/src/ :

```
public class TrySrc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryJar.hello();
    }
}
```

I tried two ways:

1.

```
javac -cp ~/jar/TryJar.jar TrySrc.java
```

it's OK during compilation, but when I try to run it, error occurs:

```
java -cp .:~/jar/TryJar.jar TrySrc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TryJar
    at TrySrc.main(TrySrc.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TryJar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

2.

I try to include in my .bashrc and .profile the following command(I don't have .bash_profile or .bash_login):

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/jar/TryJar.jar
```

and:

```
source .bashrc
source .profile
```

But this time, it's still wrong:

```
javac TrySrc.java
TrySrc.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        TryJar.hello();
        ^
  symbol:   variable TryJar
  location: class TrySrc
```

What should I do to include the external jar file?

EDIT:
The total project contains only two directories:

```
~/jar/:
   TryJar.java
   TryJar.class
   TryJar.jar
~/src/:
   TrySrc.java
```

Jar's structure:

```
jar tf TryJar.jar 
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
TryJar.class
```

My system is Ubuntu 12.04, java version:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Hopefully this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230), might be able to help you a bit :-)

Comment: Have look at [Working with Manifest Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Answer (score 2):

in your way **1:**

try changing from

```
java -cp ~/jar/TryJar.jar TrySrc
```

to

```
java -cp .:~/jar/TryJar.jar TrySrc
```

to include current directory in classpath as well to be able to load `TrySrc`

Comment: I tried your way, but same error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TryJar
    at TrySrc.main(TrySrc.java:3)"

Comment: can you post the jar's directory structure

Comment: I've update the structure, Basically the whole creation of this project is mentioned above, it's the simplest case, and I believe I made some stupid mistake, I don't know where is it...

Comment: I meant jar's structure

Comment: put this line in `main`'s method in first statement `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` and post the output also make sure all the file/directories exists which this one outputs related to the directory from where you invoke `java` command

Comment: .:~/jar/TryJar.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TryJar
 at TrySrc.main(TrySrc.java:4)

Comment: now your jar file exists at `~/jar/TryJar.jar` ? can you make sure by `ls -la ~/jar/TryJar.jar`

Comment: Yes, my jar file exists at ~/jar/TryJar.jar

Answer (score 0):

Its failing at compile time. try to import "TryJar" in TrySrc.java first.