# Where should I move Java library jar files that I downloaded?

Tags: java, api, jar

I have just downloaded a java library. It is zip file. After extracting I have found that it consists of jar files. Now what am I supposed to do with it? Where do I copy these files so that I can access them from the java code.

Comment: Make a folder in your project, put the jars in there. Then add the folder/jars to your build path.

Comment: How do I add folders/jars to my build path. I am not using eclipse. Just vim.

Comment: Don't use the term 'paste' with files. It's "Where do I move them?"

Comment: Hopefully [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230), will be of some help, on the topic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is an excellent answer to that [in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath). 
Basically you tell the compiler and/or the runtime explicitly where the jars are.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can extract your libraries where ever you want, but I you have to pass their path as an arguments to the `java` and `javac` commands in order to compile and to run your application