# How can I import classes that are located inside a referenced library?

Tags: java, eclipse, default-package

I've created a .jar file with the classes I need for my project. I created the build path for that .jar file. However, I cannot use the classes inside the referenced library that was created. So far, as I can tell, the problem is that my files (which are all .class) are located inside the default package inside the referenced library. How do I fix this?

Comment: So as the library is created by yourself, can you modify the source code to put the classes into a named package?

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11150286/1057230), hopefully it helps :-)